# Generate a 3D surface plot by fitting over many 2D plots with varying z value

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure, surface

I would like to achieve a 3D surface plot. My outputs are as follows.

For a particular value of z, I get y for each value of x (x ranges like `0:0.1:1.4`).

Then I vary z and, for the same range of x, I get y values.

The result can be visualised as 2D plots at discrete z values, consisting of the range of x and its corresponding y. Here is my original plot:

[image: plot]

I would like to create a 3D surface plot instead, like a blanket wrapped over the above 2D plots.

Comment: It is not as easy as you imagine to follow your thoughts / description. Please add your code and an example of input/output (see [ask]). This will allow us to help you easier

Comment: _I would like to create a 3D plot. I_ You need to specify _how_ you want that plot. A set of x-y curves in 3D space, one for each z? A surface y=f(x,z)? An image y=f(x,z), where y is shown as different colors on the x,z plane? Are the x values always the same for  each z?

Comment: @LuisMendo: Ya, set of xy curves in 3D space one for each z. a surface. yes x values always the same for each z

Comment: The image you added clarifies it a bit. What's the _z_ axis in that image? From your description it would seem it's the one label with letters, is it?

Comment: @LuisMendo: Ya. z axis is with labels. X axis is same for all the individual plots in the figure. Could you pls let me know how to get surface plot? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an example for the two types of plots:

```
figure
hold on
grid on
view(30,40)
x = 0:.01:4;
z = .3:.3:3;
y = NaN(numel(x), numel(z));
for k = 1:numel(z)
    y(:,k) = abs((4-x).*sin(x/(1+z(k)))); % compute a vector as function output
        % for input vector x, for each z. Store as a column in matrix y
    plot3(x,repmat(z(k),size(x)),y(:,k)) % plot in 3D space
end

figure
surf(x,z,y.','edgecolor','none') % surface plot
view(30,40)
grid on
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. It really helped. Highly appreciated.

Comment: Hey, When I add labels, they are not aligned to the axis. Do you have any idea why it is?

Comment: @KGV How are you adding the labels, exactly?

Comment: Just like the following. Similar way as how we do for 2d plots. 
    surf(x,z,y.','FaceAlpha',1.0)
    xlabel('Non-Dimensional Number (k_0a)')
    ylabel('Non-Dimensional Horizontal Force (HF_P)')
    zlabel('Non-Dimensional Porous Parameter (G_S)')
    view(30,40)
    grid on. I am actually expecting labels along their respective axis.