# Covering 2D plots with 3D surface

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, mplot3d, matplotlib-3d

I am attempting to **take many xz plots**, each **at various y values**, and **overlay a surface**. I have seen many examples of how to plot 3D surfaces in python, but aside from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46949455/generate-a-3d-surface-plot-by-fitting-over-many-2d-plots-with-varying-z-value), nothing seems to match my inquiry very closely.

The image of what I need to do is shown below (**Note:** ignore the "constant x" - this is due to a more complicated variable layout than I explained here):

[image: Magnitude vs. Frequency]

My code is as follows, and simply takes data and plots each of the individual Magnitude vs. Frequency plots (xz plots):

```
import numpy as np
import glob, os
import codecs
import re
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------                   
os.chdir('C:/Users/elarrick/Desktop/201807161056')
dataFolders = glob.glob('./*.ltda')

dataLines = []
freq = []
OpenLoopMag = []
OpenLoopPhase = []
for item in dataFolders:
    name, ext = os.path.splitext(item)
    if ext == '.ltda':
        print item
        dataLines = []
        f = codecs.open(item, encoding='utf-8')
        for line in f:
            if '<p>' in line:
                dataLines.append(line)      #All lines with <p> are an entry in dataLines
        #print "\n\n", dataLines
        #break
        for item in dataLines:
            item = re.sub("<p>", "", item)
            item = re.sub("True</p>", "", item)
            item = item.replace(",", "")
            splitItem = item.split()
            #print splitItem
            freq.append(float(splitItem[0]))
            OpenLoopMag.append(float(splitItem[1]))
            OpenLoopPhase.append(float(splitItem[2]))
        print "Frequencies: ", freq
        print "\n\n\n\n\n\nOpenLoopMag: ", OpenLoopMag
#   This is where I will make the plots for each x,y position
        name = name.strip(".\\")
        name = name.replace("-","NEG")
        plt.semilogx(freq, OpenLoopMag)
        #plt.plot(freq, OpenLoopMag)
        plt.xlabel("Frequency, (Hz)")
        plt.ylabel("Magnitude")
        plt.title("{0}".format(name))
        plt.xlim([20,2000])
        #plt.ylim([-43.2,10.9])
        ticks = [20,40,70,100,200,400,700,1000,2000]
        plt.xticks(ticks,ticks)
        plt.savefig("plot_{0}.png".format(name))

#________ Clear the values for the next data folder_______#            
        freq = []
        OpenLoopMag = []
        OpenLoopPhase = []
        break
    else:
        print "Something went wrong - check ColorMap.py"
        sys.exit()
```

**The next thing I need is to grab each plot, find the y value at which the data was taken, and plot along a y axis (shown coming out of the page in the previous picture)**. Can you help me do that?

Comment: I have the impression the last plot shown in the answer is what you're asking about. Should this not be the case, would you be able to point more prominently to where exactly the problem lies or what should be different?

Comment: Ignore that last picture - I was trying to show what Jacob Madsen's code gave me. The thing I am interested in is getting multiple of my plots (each at various y values) and laying a surface over top of them.

Answer (score 7):

Here is an example that resembles your drawing quite well.

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib.collections import PolyCollection
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Generate test data
Ny,Nx = 100,100
x = np.linspace(0,1,Nx)
y = np.linspace(0,1,Ny)
x,y = np.meshgrid(x,y)
z = (1 - x**2) * y**.5

# Indices for the y-slices and corresponding slice positions along y-axis
slice_i = [20, 40, 60, 80]
slice_pos = np.array(slice_i) / Ny

def polygon_under_graph(x, y):
    '''
    Construct the vertex list which defines the polygon filling the space under
    the (x, y) line graph.  Assumes the xlist are in ascending order.
    '''
    return [(x[0], 0.)] + list(zip(x, y)) + [(x[-1], 0.)]

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

verts = []
for i in slice_i:
    verts.append(polygon_under_graph(x[i], z[i]))

poly = PolyCollection(verts, facecolors='gray', edgecolors='k')

# add slices to 3d plot
ax.add_collection3d(poly, zs=slice_pos, zdir='y')

# plot surface between first and last slice as a mesh
ax.plot_surface(x[slice_i[0]:slice_i[-1]], 
                y[slice_i[0]:slice_i[-1]],
                z[slice_i[0]:slice_i[-1]], 
                rstride=10, cstride=10, alpha=0, edgecolors='k')

ax.set_xlabel('X')
ax.set_ylabel('Y')
ax.set_zlabel('Z')

plt.show()
```

See result:

[image: slices along axis in 3d]

Comment: That python code isn't giving me what your image shows. Unfortunately I can't include the image in a comment, so I'll edit my post so you can see what it gets me.

Comment: I just ran the code and got the figure I posted again, hence I have a hard time finding the issue. I am using Matplotlib version 2.2.2.

Comment: Interesting. I am running the same... Are you using python 2.7? My version is python 2.7.15.

Comment: I use python 3.6, but I don't think that is the issue. The problem could be the matplotlib backend. You can check this using "matplotlib.get_backend()", I get "TkAgg".

Comment: Your problem with my code is probably related to [this known bug](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/3884). It does not look like it has been resolved.

Comment: That's quite alright. The idea is there, and thus, so is your bounty. Thanks!